# Scala Unit Testing using mockito library

Tags: scala, testing, mockito, akka-http

I am writing rest test cases in akk-http, I am getting  this error in statement `when(mockedRepository.getAllFromModule).thenReturn(x)`.My Class is as below:

```
class GetModulesRestTest extends WordSpec with Matchers with ScalatestRouteTest with MockitoSugar {


  val mockedRepository = mock[ImplModuleRepository]
  val dummyRoutes = new GetModulesRest().routes
  val inputData = Modules(1L,Some("ModuleName"), Some("SomeDescription"), false)


val dataJson = """[{"id": 1,"name": "HR","description": "This is about HR module","isRemoved": false}]"""

  "Check Software Test" should {

"check for java and zookeeper installation" in {

  val x = Future(Seq(inputData))

  when(mockedRepository.getAllFromModule).thenReturn(x)
  Get("/getmodules") ~> dummyRoutes ~> check {

    responseAs[String] shouldBe dataJson
  }
}
  }
}
```

Here `ImplModuleRepository` is an abstract class which is returning list of all modules from postgres database, the program is showing error as stated above, actually statement theReturn(x) is not compiling and is showing this error on compiling:

```
Error:(32, 47) overloaded method value thenReturn with alternatives:

  (x$1: scala.concurrent.Future[Seq[com.reactore.launchpad.entity.Modules]],x$2: scala.concurrent.Future[Seq[com.reactore.launchpad.entity.Modules]]*)org.mockito.stubbing.OngoingStubbing[scala.concurrent.Future[Seq[com.reactore.launchpad.entity.Modules]]] <and>
  (x$1: scala.concurrent.Future[Seq[com.reactore.launchpad.entity.Modules]])org.mockito.stubbing.OngoingStubbing[scala.concurrent.Future[Seq[com.reactore.launchpad.entity.Modules]]]
 cannot be applied to (scalaz.concurrent.Future[Seq[com.reactore.launchpad.entity.Modules]])
      when(mockedRepository.getAllFromModule).thenReturn(x)
```

I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: It looks like you are importing, and so using, the Scalaz version of Future in the test, but not in `ImplModuleRepository`.

Comment: thanks a lot @Shadowlands , i got it now, been stuck with me for last 2 hours, thanks a lot again

Comment: No problem - sometimes you just need someone to look at the same thing with fresh eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(From the comments):*

It looks like you are importing, and so using, the Scalaz version of Future in the test, but not in `ImplModuleRepository`.